# HIVE ERROR: I am getting EOF error at 1, for the WHERE clause following the ON clause for the first LEFT OUTER JOIN , for the following code in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
select *
from table1 a

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
   select * 
   from table99
   where col = 1
)b

ON (a.col1 = b.col1)

WHERE a.col2 = b.col2 AND SIGN(a.col3) = 1


LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
   select *
   from table99
   where col = 2
)c

ON (a.col1 = c.col1)

WHERE a.col2 = c.col2 AND SIGN(a.col3) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

A properly formed SQL query has only one `where` clause (not counting CTEs and subqueries).  So:

```
select *
from table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (select * 
      from table99
      where col = 1
     ) b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
        a.col2 = b.col2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (select *
      from table99
      where col = 2
     ) c
     ON a.col1 = c.col1 AND
        a.col2 = c.col2
WHERE SIGN(a.col3) = 1;
```

However, this seems too complicated.  How about this?

```
select *
from table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     table99 b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
        a.col2 = b.col2 AND
        b.col = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table99 c
     ON a.col1 = c.col1 AND
        a.col2 = c.col2 AND
        c.col = 2 
WHERE a.col3 > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need the parenthesis in this statement `ON (a.col1 = b.col1)`, and I agree with Gordon that you should combing your on and where staements